# ReferenceError: yes is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am learning to code javascript, and have written this code

```
var userAnswer = prompt("are you feeling lucky, punk?");
if (userAnswer === yes)
{
console.log("Batman hits you very hard. It's Batman and you're you! Of course Batman wins!");
}
else
{
console.log("You did not say yes to feeling lucky. Good choice! You are a winner in the game of not getting beaten up by Batman.");
}
```

But when I run it, I get
    ReferenceError: yes is not defined.

Comment: `if (userAnswer === 'yes')`...

Answer (score 1):

When you don't enclose `yes` in quotes (i.e. a string literal), JavaScript looks for a variable with the name `yes`.  You haven't defined a variable with the name `yes`, so it throws your error.

Add quotes as such to determine if `userAnswer` contains the string `yes`:

```
if (userAnswer === 'yes')
```

If you want to accept different cases (i.e. `Yes` and `YES`), you can use `.toLowerCase()`

```
if (userAnswer.toLowerCase() === 'yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare the *variable* `userAnswer` with another *variable* `yes`. The problem is that you have not defined `yes`. I believe you are trying to compare `userAnswer` with the *string literal* "yes".

So if you changed `userAnswer === yes` to `userAnswer === "yes"` it should do what you want.